# Spellchecker for Linux with Latex support and export option?

Tags: software-recommendation, spell-checking

i'm looking for a command-line spellchecker with Latex input support and an option for exporting a report with all the problems it found in the file. ispell is interactive and doesn't export a report, aspell also doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
aspell list -t < somefile.tex
```

gets you a list of all misspelled words in `somefile.tex`

Comment: +1, good shot. I expanded to `aspell list -t -l en --encoding=ISO-8859-1 <file.tex | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 | sort -u`